# Как вытащить время создания файла и по своему отформатировать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, datetime, python-3.7

Есть список файлов с названиями вида "fileName.txt".
И есть задание: переименовать файлы в формате "old_fileName_2020-09-23T15:25.txt"

Как вытащить время создания файла, да еще и нужным образом отформатировать его?

К слову, в каждом файле есть дата создания этого файла в текстовом виде, если что. Но находится оно там не в ISO формате.

Нагуглил следующую инфу:
Вот этот код:

```
from os.path import getctime
from time import ctime

print(ctime(getctime('fileName.txt')))
```

Выводит информацию о файле в виде `Tue Dec  8 20:35:22 2020`
И судя по всему, эту тупиковый путь.
Можно, конечно, попытаться срезами повырезать из текста отдельные участки и по-вставлять их куда нужно, но это слишком сложное решение для такого простого назначения.

Есть ли какая-то альтернатива?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю это то, что вам нужно:

```py
from os.path import getctime
import datetime


print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(getctime('fileName.txt')).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Подробнее про форматирование можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Да, это именно то, что нужно.

Comment: Рад, что помог!